# Nginx process upper level directives

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, location

I'm configuring my nginx server with fpm-php and getting some trouble:

I want nginx to apply some directives defined in "upper level" locations and also more precise locations.  I'll explain myself:

```
/admin {
  # apply auth-basic directives
}

location ~* \.php$ {
  # apply fpm-php proxy directives (php processing)
}
```

I want URL
/admin/example.php

to process both directives, so authorization and php processing both apply.  But as per location precedence on nginx first, any regular expression takes precedence over prefix locations, resulting in no auth-basic directives been applied.

I've managed to get this working including the upper level config inside the other location:

```
/admin {
    # apply auth-basic directives
    # apply fpm-php proxy directives (php processing)
}

location ~* /admin/(.*)\.php$ {
    # apply auth-basic directives
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    # apply fpm-php proxy directives (php processing)
}
```

But I think this is againt DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and quite uncomfortable :(  Even using include directive.

Do you know any better way of doing this?

Thanks guys! ^_^

Comment: Use `include` and nested locations.